# Writing files to Parquet format in Java?

Tags: java, parquet

While researching on writing files to Parquet in Java I came across -

1. org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter
2. org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter

But both have been deprecated. What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

`AvroParquetWriter` itself shouldn't be deprecated. Its constructors are deprecated, in favor of a static method [`builder​(org.apache.parquet.io.OutputFile file)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.parquet/parquet-avro/latest/org/apache/parquet/avro/AvroParquetWriter.html#builder(org.apache.parquet.io.OutputFile)).